# Adding to a Model's IList with a form in ASP.Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In trying to learn ASP.Net Core, I decided that making a forum would be a good learning project.

In that vein I created these models:

```
public class Topic
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int PostCount {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string OriginalPoster {get; set;}
    public IList<Post> Posts{get; set;}
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime TimeStamp {get; set;}
    public string Poster {get; set;}
    public string Body {get; set;}
}
```

Now, obviously when one creates a forum Topic, one should also create their first post lest you be left with a headless title.

Therefore, I created this form with the impression that it would get me that first post (and once that's working I could handle the other parts of the Post model pretty easily):

```
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Topic" method = "post">
<div class="form-group"><label asp-for="Title"></label>
<input asp-for="Title"></div>

@Html.TextAreaFor(e => e.Posts[0].Body, 10, 55, null) <br />


<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

However when I put a breakpoint in the `Create` method of my `TopicController` it is showing me that this is not working (which I suspect is due to my never creating a new Post instance).  I get:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrency Exception

saying that 1 row was expected to be affected, however 0 rows were affected by my Database Context's `SaveChanges` method. Is there any way to create a new Post instance and add it to my `IList<Post>` from this form?

The `Create` function of my controller is below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Topic tops)
    {
        if (tops is null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(tops));
        }

        tops.Posts[0].TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        db.Topics.Add(tops);
        db.SaveChanges();  // <-- Error happens here

        return View("Topics", db.Topics.ToList());
    }
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated.

The MySQL table for Topics are as follows:

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id             | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PostCount      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Title          | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| OriginalPoster | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And for Post:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| TimeStamp | datetime(6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Poster    | longtext    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Body      | longtext    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Have you ever try changing the `IList<Post>` to an array like `Post[]`?

Comment: *" it is showing me that this is not working"* -- Can you help us out by giving us more detail? Is there an error? Or just not the behaviour you expected?  What does "not working" mean?

Comment: I have updated my question to be more descriptive of the errors I am seeing.

Comment: ok, thanks. That helps. I suspect there are multiple things that need fixing here. First, let's do this... when you hit your breakpoint at your `Create(Topic tops)` method, and hover over `tops`, what does that object look like?  Does it have everything you expect it to have?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston It does yes, the things I expect to be null are null and the things I expect to be not null are not null.  Specifically Posts is of length 1 with a body consisting of the message I created in the form and the timestamp is also being generated.  The Id of the Post in Posts is 0, which I think shows that it is being assigned the zeroth id in the database.

Comment: And just to be clear, the error is happening here: `db.SaveChanges();` Correct?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you SaveChanges? Are you wanting EF to save both the `Topic` and the `Post` to their respective tables?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is where the error is showing up, and that is my desired effect.

Comment: (@Mascasc -- see my comment above about what you are expecting to happen. Just want to be sure you didn't miss it.)

Comment: @CaseyCrookston, sorry, I tried to reply to both comments at once and ended up being unclear.  Yes, that is what I'm wanting to happen.

Comment: Can  you show us the SQL tables that match the `Topic` and `Post` models?

Comment: I have posted the tables above.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere! The bottom line is: I think you need to spend a little more time learning about the following: 1) Data Relationships,2)  Relational Tables, and 3) How Entity Framework handles data relationships. But, let's start here... I assume from your post that the relatiosbhip between `Topic` and `Post` is 1:Many.  Meaning 1 Topic can have many Posts. But each Post can only belong to one Topic.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct relationship.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue by using your code.It works well in my project.Could you share what is your `db`?Did you use EF Core?

Comment: Did you modify your class after updating your database?If so,use the command `update-database` again and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after our conversation in the comments, I'll take a stab at an answer.

First, you'll need to make some changes to your database tables.

1. The ID on the `Topics` table should be auto_incrementing.
2. Your `Post` table needs to have a Foreign Key in it that relates back to the `Topics` table. Without that, we have no way of knowing which `Post` a `Topic` belongs to.  If you do it right, that relationship should actually be defined in the database. In other words, don't just add the FK column. Take the extra step to tell SQL that it relates back to the parent table. You can google how to do this. Examples abound.
3. I would *really* not name your ID columns `Id`.  Let them have unique names.  `PostId` and `TopicId`. This will save you a LOT of headaches.

Now, let's take a look at your Models in your code. The way you make the relationship in code is by defining the foreign key in the `Post` model. In your case, that would look like this:

```
public class Topic
{
    [Key]
    public int TopicId {get; set;}
    public int PostCount {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string OriginalPoster {get; set;}
    public IList<Post> Posts{get; set;}
}

public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId {get; set;}
    ForeignKey("Topic")]
    public int TopicId{get; set;}
    public DateTime TimeStamp {get; set;}
    public string Poster {get; set;}
    public string Body {get; set;}
}
```

Now, EF is going to know that these two classes relate to each other, and how.

I ***think*** that this should be enough to get your code to work. But if you run into any other problems, either post a comment below or start a new question (and post a comment below with a link to the new question).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

#### Reason

1. I think you don't actually write to the database, The IList < post > field in your topic model does not really exist in the database, so you cannot insert it.

#### Solution

1. There are problems in database design. This is a typical one to many data set problem. You need to associate the two tables with foreign keys so that you can update your post table according to the key values.
2. Your database table should be modified to look like this

```
    public class Topic
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int TopicId { get; set; }
        public int PostCount { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string OriginalPoster { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public int TopicId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("TopicId")]
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public string Poster { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
```

3. I copied your code and put it on GitHub. You can click this [link](https://github.com/jianba/ASP.NET-Core-MVC-with-EF-Core---tutorial-series/blob/master/ContosoUniversity/Controllers/TopicController.cs) to see how I can implement an insert operation.This is the code for the insert part

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateTopic(TopicViewModel model)
        {
            var topic = new Topic
            {
                Title = model.Title,
                OriginalPoster = model.OriginalPoster,
                PostCount = model.PostCount
            };
            await _context.AddAsync(topic);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePost(PostViewModel model)
        {
            var post = new Post
            {
                TopicId = model.TopicId,
                TimeStamp = model.TimeStamp,
                Poster = model.Poster,
                Body = model.Body
            };
            await _context.AddAsync(post);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

4. Through the above description and code should be able to solve your current problem.

#### Other Tips

1. There are some deviations in your understanding of the Model in .Net core. Model can be divided into two types: mapping database entities and providing services for front-end page work. Related [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application).
2. The documentation of. Net core is not very comprehensive. Many small knowledge can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/index).